# How do I recursively lookup and sum?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

| Item | Ingredient 1 | Count | Ingredient 2 | Count | Ingredient 3 | Count | Ingredient 4 | Count | Ingredient 5 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SCAR Assault Rifle | Plywood Board | 2 | Copper Alloy | 6 | Normal Leather | 3 | Rare Metal | 2 |  |  |
| Plywood Board | Wood | 350 | Ash Branch | 5 | Small Animal Hide | 4 | Ash Wood | 3 | Animal Sinew | 1 |
| Copper Alloy | Stone | 90 | Ash Branch | 4 | Copper Ore | 5 | Ash Wood | 1 | Malachite | 3 |
| Normal Leather | Grease | 15 | Prairie Flaxseed | 4 | Small Animal Hide | 5 | Prairie Flax Fibers | 1 | Animal Sinew | 3 |

I have the following table, where I want to find the base materials when constructing an item. These base materials are not included in the table, namely:
Wood, Ash Branches, Ash Wood, Stones, Small Animal Hide, Animal Sinew, Meat, Copper Ore, Prairie Flaxseed

How do I find out which base materials and how much do I need for an item like SCAR Assault Rifle?

I tried using arrayformula but failed doing so, and I have a searchmaterial function as such:

```
=QUERY(Index!$A$2:$K, "SELECT B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K WHERE LOWER(A) contains '"&LOWER(args1)&"'")
```

where args1 would be the item that I want its material searched

I am also not aware of what functions to use. I think arrayformula and sumproduct may help me but I cannot figure out how to piece them together.

I'm not well-versed in excel formulas, and would appreciate any help/pointers. Thank you in advance.

Sample spreadsheet with input and expected output: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11pCNG0aHOPk7JPpzFt2j4mC4FWCljm86ZxdKzSo3mW8/edit#gid=105611565

Comment: please consider sharing a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).

Comment: Please, note Excel **is not** the same than Google Sheets, so use the right tags.

Comment: like ztiaa said, I would be willing to help, but recreating your spreadsheet from a screenshot isn't my idea of fun 

Comment: @ztiaa Thanks a lot! I've created a spreadsheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11pCNG0aHOPk7JPpzFt2j4mC4FWCljm86ZxdKzSo3mW8/edit#gid=105611565

Comment: @Mark added the sample spreadsheet too. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive formula that solves this problem.

```
=SORT(
   LET(data,{TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(Data!1:1,"Ingredient*")),TOROW(Data!A2:A)),,1),WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Data!B2:INDEX(Data!B2:ZZZ,,-1+MATCH(,(Data!1:1="")*COLUMN(Data!1:1)))),2)},
       items,INDEX(data,,1),
       ingredients,INDEX(data,,2),
       qty,INDEX(data,,3),
       F,LAMBDA(F,i,q,QUERY(REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(ROWS(i)),LAMBDA(a,c,IFNA(VSTACK(a,LET(_i,INDEX(i,c),_q,INDEX(q,c),IF(COUNTIF(items,_i)=0,{A2,_i,_q},F(F,FILTER(ingredients,items=_i),FILTER(qty*_q,items=_i)))))))),"where Col2 is not null",)),
       r,F(F,FILTER(ingredients,items=A2),FILTER(qty,items=A2)),
       {UNIQUE(INDEX(r,,2)),MAP(UNIQUE(INDEX(r,,2)),LAMBDA(_i,SUM(FILTER(INDEX(r,,3),INDEX(r,,2)=_i))))}))
```

We are creating a custom recursive function `F(F,i,q,...)` that replaces the appropriate values by repeatedly calling itself until there are no ​more values to replace.

[image]

The interesting part is:

```
=LET(...,
     F,LAMBDA(F,i,q,
            REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(ROWS(i)),
            LAMBDA(a,c,IFNA(VSTACK(a,LET(_i,INDEX(i,c),_q,INDEX(q,c),
                       IF(COUNTIF(items,_i)=0,{A2,_i,_q},
                       F(F,FILTER(ingredients,items=_i),FILTER(qty*_q,items=_i))))))))
    ,...)
```

We are first declaring `F(F,i,q)`, which is a recursive function that takes 3 arguments: itself, an array of ingredients and an array of quantities.

Then we use `REDUCE` with the accumulator `a` initialized to an empty array and the current values `c` initialized to every number from 1 to the amount of rows in the arrays provided to the recursive function.

Inside the REDUCE function we are declaring two variables `_i` and `_q` which correspond to the current ingredient and its corresponding required quantity.

The base case, which stops the execution of the recursive function is

```
COUNTIF(items,_i)=0
```

Which is TRUE when the current ingredient does not appear in the list of items. When this condition is TRUE, we just stack the item we are looking for, the current ingredient and its corresponding quantity to the accumulator

```
VSTACK(a,...{A2,_i,_q},...)
```

If the condition is FALSE it means that the current ingredient appears in the list of items so we call the recursive function again by filtering the items and quantities based on the current ingredient. This is the recursive step.

```
F(F,FILTER(ingredients,items=_i),FILTER(qty*_q,items=_i))))))))
```

This is pretty much the core of the formula, the rest of the formula is rearranging the input table in a better way, declaring variables and cleaning the output.

Answer (score 0):

*One more approach to try out:*

```js
=let(inp_,'Input/Expected Output'!A2, rep_,Data!A2:A, grp_,Data!B2:K, size_,2, Σ,reduce(wraprows(,columns(rep_)+size_,),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,{a;{rep_,choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}})),x,filter(Σ,index(Σ,,column(grp_))<>""),
     it,index(x,,1), ix,index(x,,2), qt,index(x,,3), 
     loop_,lambda(rec_,Λ, reduce(,Λ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(iserror(filter(ix,it=c)),c,rec_(rec_,let(Σ,filter({ix,qt},it=c),tocol(map(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2),lambda(x,y,wraprows(x,y,x))),3)))))))),
     z,tocol(loop_(loop_,inp_),1),sort(map(unique(tocol(z,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,countif(z,Σ)})),2,)
```

[image]

***`Formula breakup`***

*`Step 1` Restructure the data from the columns `A:K` to `O:Q`*

```js
=let(rep_,A2:A, grp_,B2:K, size_,2,Σ,reduce(wraprows(,columns(rep_)+size_,),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,{a;{rep_,choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}})),filter(Σ,index(Σ,,column(grp_))<>""))
```

*`Step 2` Implement recursive Fx to create a loop & keep on filtering the ingredients(while multiplying quantity)*

```js
=let(inp_,M2, rep_,A2:A, grp_,B2:K, size_,2, Σ,reduce(wraprows(,columns(rep_)+size_,),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,{a;{rep_,choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}})),x,filter(Σ,index(Σ,,column(grp_))<>""), it,index(x,,1), ix,index(x,,2), qt,index(x,,3), loop_,lambda(rec_,Λ, reduce(,Λ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(iserror(filter(ix,it=c)),c,rec_(rec_,let(Σ,filter({ix,qt},it=c),tocol(map(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2),lambda(x,y,wraprows(x,y,x))),3)))))))), tocol(loop_(loop_,inp_),1))
```

*`Step 3` again just restructuring the output obtained in step_2 to final output design*

```js
=let(inp_,M2, rep_,A2:A, grp_,B2:K, size_,2, Σ,reduce(wraprows(,columns(rep_)+size_,),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,{a;{rep_,choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}})),x,filter(Σ,index(Σ,,column(grp_))<>""), it,index(x,,1), ix,index(x,,2), qt,index(x,,3), loop_,lambda(rec_,Λ, reduce(,Λ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(iserror(filter(ix,it=c)),c,rec_(rec_,let(Σ,filter({ix,qt},it=c),tocol(map(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2),lambda(x,y,wraprows(x,y,x))),3)))))))), z,tocol(loop_(loop_,inp_),1),sort(map(unique(tocol(z,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,countif(z,Σ)})),2,))
```

[image]